# get a variable value from select and pass this to another JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I experience a problem to get value from select and put it on a var.

HTML

```
<select id="customer_select"" name="customer_select" class="select" onchange="findcustid(this.value)" >';
```

JS

```
function findcustid() {
    var cus = document.getElementById('customer_select');
    var customer_select = cus.options[cus.selectedIndex].value;
}
var customer_id = customer_select;
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `customer_select` is local to `findcustid` and does not exist when you execute `var customer_id = customer_select;`. What exactly is the issue you claim to have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your customer_select variable is local to function to its scope will not be available outside the function.

```
var customer_id;
function findcustid() {
    var cus = document.getElementById('customer_select');
    customer_id = document.getElementById('customer_select').value;
}
```

Another way you can do this if not using a global cutomer_id variable is by setting it in the current `window` instance
ex:-

```
function findcustid() {
    var cus = document.getElementById('customer_select');
    window.customer_id = document.getElementById('customer_select').value;
}
```

now you can access `window.customer_id` in any function defined in the scope of the current window.

Answer (score 1):

You select HTML has to many ", start with changing to:

```
<select id="customer_select" name="customer_select" class="select" onchange="findcustid(this.value)" >
```

Also, you closed the function before you set the customer_id, change to

```
function findcustid() {
    var cus = document.getElementById('customer_select');
    var customer_select = cus.options[cus.selectedIndex].value;
    var customer_id = customer_select;
    alert(customer_id);
}
```

You can not set the item after the function is closed. Because the function is not called yet but the code is executed. So in the end with your code, `customer_id` would be `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

First off Niels is correct that you closed your function before you did anything with your variable.
Two possible solutions.

Also, I'm a little confused by what you mean "pass to another JS file" ... you can't pass it to another page without making it a url or form variable and going to that page.

or .. if the js includes are on the same page, just declare this function before calling it from any other included functions:

```
<script src="../customerFuncs.js"></script> 
<script src="../useCustomerFuncs.js"></script>
```

1. if you need customer_id somewhere else, set it as the return value of the function and call that function from another function, ala:

   ```
   function  findcustid(){
       var cus = document.getElementById('customer_select');
       var customer_select = cus.options[cus.selectedIndex].value;
       var customer_id = customer_select;
       return customer_id;
   }

   function getId(){
       customer_id = findcustid();
   }
   ```
2. you can make it a global variable accessible by any function. you do this by declaring it outside any function scope. this method is really frowned upon, as it's not usually necessary.

   ```
   gCustomer_Id = '';

   function  findcustid(){ 
       ... 
       gCustomer_Id = customer_select;
   }
   ```